# How to customize the docker run command on Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Here's the thing, I need to tell Docker to not containerize the container’s networking, because it needs to connect to a MongoDB that is inside a VPN (enterprise private DB).

There is a Docker command that let's me do exactly that: `--net=host`. Reference [here](https://docs.docker.com/articles/networking/#how-docker-networks-a-container).

So, for example, when running the container on my local machine, I will do something like:

```
docker run --rm -it --net=host [image-name]:[version] bash -il
```

And that command will do the trick. Thanks to that, I can connect to the "private" MongoDB.

So, my question is: Is there a way customize the `docker run` command of a Single Docker Environment on Elastic Beanstalk so I can add the `--net=host`?

I have tried using the [container_commands](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#customize-containers-format-container_commands) into the `config.yml` file to add that instruction there, but I don't think that does what I need, here is a snippet:

```
container_commands:
  00-test_command:
    command: bundle exec thin --net=host
  01-networking-fix:
    command: "docker run --rm -it --net=host [image-name]:[version] bash -il"
```

Answer (score 12):

I ended up fixing it with two container commands

```
container_commands:
  00_fix_networking:
    command: sed -i 's/docker run -d/docker run --net=host -d/' /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/enact/00run.sh
  01_fix_docker_ip:
    command: sed -i 's/server $EB_CONFIG_NGINX_UPSTREAM_IP/server localhost/' /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/enact/01flip.sh
```

*Update*: 
I also had to fix the Upstart script. Unfortunately, I didn't write down what I did because I didn't end up needing to alter the `docker run` command. You would do a `files` directive for (I think) `/etc/init/docker`. AWS edits the Nginx configuration in the same manner as in `01flip.sh` in that file as well.

---

Explanation:

In the `64bit Amazon Linux 2015.03 v2.0.2 running Docker 1.7.1` platform version, the file you need to edit is `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/enact/00run.sh`. This file is now far more complex than Samar's version so I didn't want to put the actual contents in there. However, the change is basically the same. There's the line that starts with

```
docker run -d
```

I fixed it with a container command:

```
container_commands:
  00_fix_networking:
    command: sed -i 's/docker run -d/docker run --net=host -d/' /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/enact/00run.sh
```

This successfully adds the `--net=host` argument but now there's another problem. The system ends up with an invalid Nginx directive. Using `--net=host` means that when you run `docker inspect <container id>` there is no IP address in the NetworkSettings. AWS uses this to create the server directive for Nginx and ends up generating `server :<some port you chose>` (before adding `--net=host` it would look like `server <ip>:<port>`). I needed to patch that file, too. It's generated in `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/enact/01flip.sh`.

```
01_fix_docker_ip:
  command: sed -i 's/server $EB_CONFIG_NGINX_UPSTREAM_IP/server localhost/' /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/enact/01flip.sh
```

Comment: This worked for me. Also this is the change I made for the upstart script that @mqsoh has indicated above in "UPDATE". ```02_eb_docker_upstart:
    command: sed -i 's/$EB_CONFIG_NGINX_UPSTREAM_IP/localhost/' /etc/init/eb-docker.conf```

Comment: @Hari: Did you get this to work for consecutive deploys? The above (and yours) container commands work for me but *only* for the first deploy. After that, the deploys fail, since they complain about addresses in use.

Comment: @nunos Unfortunately I did not get to test that out - I eventually ended up not using host networking. Sorry !

Comment: @mqsoh as you didn't end up using this solution because of all the side effects, can you point me to what you DID do, as your update is super unclear. Especially now since the Upstart for docker has changed drastically since this post.

Comment: @Relic, I tried to give as much info as I had back then. I stopped using Beanstalk altogether shortly thereafter, so I'm unfortunately not able to help you.

Comment: So what did you end up doing to deploy? My purpose is a Neo4J HA Cluster and that's not exactly an AWS Service

Answer (score 3):

While elastic beanstalk is generally well suited for applications that work with standard set of configurations, its difficult to customize and keep things updated along with the updates AWS provides to EB stacks. Having said that, I've done something like below which is a bit hacky but works fine.

```
files:
    "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/04run.sh":
      mode: "000755"
      owner: root
      group: root
      encoding: plain
      content: |
        #script content of original 04run.sh along with modification on docker run cmd
        # eg. I injected multi-ports here
        docker run -d \
               "${EB_CONFIG_DOCKER_ENV_ARGS[@]}" \
               "${EB_CONFIG_DOCKER_VOLUME_MOUNTS[@]}" \
               "${EB_CONFIG_DOCKER_ENTRYPOINT_ARGS[@]}" \
               "${PORT_ARGS[@]}" \
               $EB_CONFIG_DOCKER_IMAGE_STAGING \
               "${EB_CONFIG_DOCKER_COMMAND_ARGS[@]}" 2>&1 | tee /tmp/docker_run.log | tee $EB_CONFIG_DOCKER_STAGING_APP_FILE
```

This is not very neat, at least I have to make sure that it does not break with updates on elastic beanstalk. The above one is for docker 1.5 stack but you can do something similar with the version you're running.

Comment: Hi Samar! I'm trying to understand your solution. In the "content" section, where or how do I add my command? Just like this: "docker run -d \ --net=host"?

Reference of the config.yml: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#customize-containers-format-files

Answer (score 2):

Note that **the latest version of the AWS stack (with Docker 1.7.1) has a slightly different pre-deploy setup**. You'll need to update the file at the location: `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/enact/00run.sh`

```
commands:
    00001_add_privileged:
         cwd: /tmp
         command: 'sed -i "s/docker run -d/docker run --privileged -d/" /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/enact/00run.sh'
```

or, for example, if you want to pass args to your Docker image:

```
commands:
    00001_modify_docker_run:
        cwd: /tmp
        command: 'sed -i "s/\$EB_CONFIG_DOCKER_IMAGE_STAGING/\$EB_CONFIG_DOCKER_IMAGE_STAGING -gzip -enable-url-source/" /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/enact/00run.sh'
```