# Docker port mapping on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a Docker container specified through Dockerfile which has to be run with the `-p` flag in order to function properly. On my local machine, after running

```
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 blagtagger:v0.4.3
```

the port mapping is shown as `0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp` and everything works smoothly.

Now, I need to deploy it on AWS Elastic Beanstalk, so I prepared my `Dockerrun.aws.json` file as follows:

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1",
  "Ports": [
    {
      "ContainerPort": 5000,
      "HostPort": 5000
    }
  ]
}
```

However, the container port does not seem to map to the host port correctly. The port mapping is shown as `5000/tcp`.

How can I ask Beanstalk to set the mapping to `0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp`?

Comment: Have you gone through this doc carefully https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/single-container-docker-configuration.html#Ports

Comment: Yes, this is exactly where I took the Dockerrun example above from. Not sure if this matters, but my Dockerfile does also state `EXPOSE 5000`, else the deployment would fail. I honestly don't know where the issue is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out there is no elegant way to accomplish this. Along the lines of the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31968404/how-to-customize-the-docker-run-command-on-elastic-beanstalk/33136221) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28267419/how-can-i-run-a-docker-container-in-aws-elastic-beanstalk-with-non-default-run-p), I added the following in a file named `.ebextensions/01-commands.config`:

```
commands:
    00001_add_port_mapping:
        cwd: /tmp
        command: 'sed -i "s/docker run -d/docker run -p 5000:5000 -d/" /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/enact/00run.sh'
```

and discarded the `Dockerrun.aws.json` file.

Comment: `docker-compose` files did not solve your problem?